# If chars are randomly inserted into a string with a prob $p$, what does $p$ need to be for the number of insertions on average to be $x$?

Tags: probability

So let's say I have a string = "taco" and I want to randomly insert 4 characters into this string. So at index=1 or at 't' I have a probability $p$ of inserting a random character and this process is run for all the letters so [t,a,c,o] all have $p$ of having a character inserted to the right of it. But I want $p$ to be defined in a way s.t. the expectation for the number of inserted characters will be 4.

The number of inserted characters can be 1-7 so that means I can insert 7 characters in "taco."

Is there a way of calculating $p$ s.t. the expectation for characters inserted equals some integer $x$?

Comment: Do you mean expected value, or the most likely value?

Answer (score 1):

There are $4$ characters in "taco", so the expected number of characters you add to "taco" is $4p$ (can you explain why?).

To make this equal $x$, we need $4p=x$, that is, $p=x/4$.